# There is a function in Zoho that used to work but it has broken and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: function, task, zoho

In Zoho CRM there are a problem with this function and I don't know how to fix it.  It is a function to delete an old task when I create new one.

I didn't try anything.

Function:

```
Leadinfo = zoho.crm.getRelatedRecords("Tasks","Leads",leadid);
for each task in Leadinfo 
{
  taskid = task.get("id"); 
  //tinfo = zoho.crm.getRecordById("Tasks",taskid);
  tdate = task.get('Due_Date').todatetime();
  tt = zoho.currentdate;
  if(tdate <= tt)
  {
    mp = Map();
    mp.put("Status","Completed");
    updateResp = zoho.crm.updateRecord("Tasks",taskid,mp); 
  }
}
info updateResp;
```

Comment: Leadinfo = zoho.crm.getRelatedRecords("Tasks","Leads",leadid);
for each  task in Leadinfo
{
 taskid = task.get("id");
 //tinfo = zoho.crm.getRecordById("Tasks",taskid);
 tdate = task.get('Due_Date').todatetime();
 tt = zoho.currentdate;
 if(tdate <= tt)
 {
  mp = Map();
  mp.put("Status","Completed");
  updateResp = zoho.crm.updateRecord("Tasks",taskid,mp);
 }
}
info updateResp;

Comment: Could you please update your question and format the function you are using? And please put the output of update response. Lastly, the output you expect.

Comment: what is the output of `info updateResp;`?